Problem with Plotting the dates on x axis for every timepoint in ggplot - and also some weird date conversion things (sidebar)
My main issue is that I want the dates to display for each time point in this figure

Don't know if this is part of it, but I struggled to convert my csv dates to R dates. As you can see from my data below (see link - removed because of comments, added dput data) I have m/d/y in my .csv file and I had to tell R that it was just %m/%d in order for all of the date data to be read correctly into R. If I did %m/%d/%Y, I got a few dates to come over, but they were like 0023/11/10 format weird and the rest were NA (like 75%).
Here is my code:

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

particle_data <- read.csv("C:/Users/.csv")

view(particle_data)

Dv50Data <- particle_data %>% 
  filter(Metric == "mean") 

Dv50Data$Dv50 <- as.numeric(as.character(Dv50Data$Dv50)) 

Dv50Data$Date <- as.Date(Dv50Data$Date, format = "%m/%d")
  
view(Dv50Data)

glimpse(Dv50Data)
  
  ggplot(Dv50Data, aes(x = Date,
                            y = Dv50,
                            group = Treatment,
                            color = Treatment)) + 
  geom_line()+
  geom_point() + 
    ylim (0,50) +
    labs(title = "Dose Response: Dv50 Particle Size Over Time",
         y = "Particle Size (microns)") + 
    scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
    theme_minimal()

Here is my df
structure(list(Species = c("OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", 
"OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", 
"OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", 
"OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", 
"OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", 
"OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", 
"OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", 
"OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", 
"OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", 
"OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", 
"OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", 
"OFAV", "OFAV"), Treatment = c("10 NTU", "10 NTU", "10 NTU", 
"10 NTU", "10 NTU", "10 NTU", "10 NTU", "10 NTU", "10 NTU", "10 NTU", 
"10 NTU", "10 NTU", "10 NTU", "10 NTU", "10 NTU", "10 NTU", "10 NTU", 
"10 NTU", "10 NTU", "10 NTU", "10 NTU", "20 NTU", "20 NTU", "20 NTU", 
"20 NTU", "20 NTU", "20 NTU", "20 NTU", "20 NTU", "20 NTU", "20 NTU", 
"20 NTU", "20 NTU", "20 NTU", "20 NTU", "20 NTU", "20 NTU", "20 NTU", 
"20 NTU", "20 NTU", "20 NTU", "20 NTU", "29 NTU", "29 NTU", "29 NTU", 
"29 NTU", "29 NTU", "29 NTU", "29 NTU", "29 NTU", "29 NTU", "29 NTU", 
"29 NTU", "29 NTU", "29 NTU", "29 NTU", "29 NTU", "29 NTU", "29 NTU", 
"29 NTU", "29 NTU", "29 NTU", "29 NTU", "Stock", "Stock", "Stock", 
"Stock", "Stock", "Stock", "Stock", "Stock", "Stock", "Stock", 
"Stock", "Stock", "Stock", "Stock", "Stock", "Stock", "Stock", 
"Stock", "Stock", "Stock", "Stock", "Stock", "Stock", "Stock"
), Date = c("09/26/23", "09/26/23", "09/26/23", "10/13/23", "10/13/23", 
"10/13/23", "10/24/23", "10/24/23", "10/24/23", "11/10/23", "11/10/23", 
"11/10/23", "11/21/23", "11/21/23", "11/21/23", "12/08/23", "12/08/23", 
"12/08/23", "12/12/23", "12/12/23", "12/12/23", "09/26/23", "09/26/23", 
"09/26/23", "10/13/23", "10/13/23", "10/13/23", "10/24/23", "10/24/23", 
"10/24/23", "11/10/23", "11/10/23", "11/10/23", "11/21/23", "11/21/23", 
"11/21/23", "12/08/23", "12/08/23", "12/08/23", "12/12/23", "12/12/23", 
"12/12/23", "09/26/23", "09/26/23", "09/26/23", "10/13/23", "10/13/23", 
"10/13/23", "10/24/23", "10/24/23", "10/24/23", "11/10/23", "11/10/23", 
"11/10/23", "11/21/23", "11/21/23", "11/21/23", "12/08/23", "12/08/23", 
"12/08/23", "12/12/23", "12/12/23", "12/12/23", "09/26/23", "09/26/23", 
"09/26/23", "10/13/23", "10/13/23", "10/13/23", "10/24/23", "10/24/23", 
"10/24/23", "11/07/23", "11/07/23", "11/07/23", "11/10/23", "11/10/23", 
"11/10/23", "11/21/23", "11/21/23", "11/21/23", "12/08/23", "12/08/23", 
"12/08/23", "12/12/23", "12/12/23", "12/12/23"), Metric = c("mean", 
"SD", "%RSD", "mean", "SD", "%RSD", "mean", "SD", "%RSD", "mean", 
"SD", "%RSD", "mean", "SD", "%RSD", "mean", "SD", "%RSD", "mean", 
"SD", "%RSD", "mean", "SD", "%RSD", "mean", "SD", "%RSD", "mean", 
"SD", "%RSD", "mean", "SD", "%RSD", "mean", "SD", "%RSD", "mean", 
"SD", "%RSD", "mean", "SD", "%RSD", "mean", "SD", "%RSD", "mean", 
"SD", "%RSD", "mean", "SD", "%RSD", "mean", "SD", "%RSD", "mean", 
"SD", "%RSD", "mean", "SD", "%RSD", "mean", "SD", "%RSD", "mean", 
"SD", "%RSD", "mean", "SD", "%RSD", "mean", "SD", "%RSD", "mean", 
"SD", "%RSD", "mean", "SD", "%RSD", "mean", "SD", "%RSD", "mean", 
"SD", "%RSD", "mean", "SD", "%RSD"), Dv50 = c("37.5", "0.354", 
"0.946", "28.6", "0.53", "1.85", "32.2", "0.07", "0.22", "27.5", 
"0.234", "0.853", "31.1", "0.138", "0.444", "28.2", "0.567", 
"2.01", "29", "0.214", "0.737", "20.2", "0.0589", "0.292", "21.9", 
"0.099", "0.453", "21.7", "0.107", "0.494", "22.1", "0.167", 
"0.758", "22.6", "0.0816", "0.361", "21.6", "0.312", "1.44", 
"19.4", "0.056", "0.289", "30.4", "0.6.6", "1.99", "15.4", "0.044", 
"0.29", "20.2", "0.107", "0.531", "18.5", "0.116", "0.626", "20.1", 
"0.07", "0.349", "18.1", "0.091", "0.507", "19.9", "0.077", "0.387", 
"26.8", "0.16", "0.596", "14.3", "0.047", "0.332", "19.2", "0.07", 
"0.365", "20.5", "0.131", "0.638", "21.4", "0.177", "0.825", 
"18", "0.016", "0.09", "20.4", "0.062", "0.306", "19.3", "0.137", 
"0.707"), Quality.Check = c("Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", 
"Pass", "Pass")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -87L
))


Hi RayzedByRobots. Many people are not going to be comfortable downloading a random file, and those who might be will find they haven't been given access. To enable people to help provide an answer to your question, and make it reproducible, please edit the question to include the output from dput(particle_data).

Hi thanks for your feedback. So you want me to post the output df?  Can I do that as a image file? Or just include a portion like I did with the code using the ``` ?

Run dput(particle_data) and you'll see some output in your console starting with structure(.... If you copy and paste that entire output into a codeblock in your question, people will be able to recreate the dataframe from read.csv() without having the file itself.

lubridate::mdy() can help parse the Date variable. I create a list of the dates in the dataset which I use to specify breaks on the x-axis scale.
library(tidyverse)

particle_data |> glimpse()
#> Rows: 87
#> Columns: 6
#> $ Species       <chr> "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", "OFAV", …
#> $ Treatment     <chr> "10 NTU", "10 NTU", "10 NTU", "10 NTU", "10 NTU", "10 NT…
#> $ Date          <chr> "09/26/23", "09/26/23", "09/26/23", "10/13/23", "10/13/2…
#> $ Metric        <chr> "mean", "SD", "%RSD", "mean", "SD", "%RSD", "mean", "SD"…
#> $ Dv50          <chr> "37.5", "0.354", "0.946", "28.6", "0.53", "1.85", "32.2"…
#> $ Quality.Check <chr> "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", "Pass", …

Dv50Data <- particle_data |>
  filter(Metric == "mean") |>
  mutate(Date = mdy(Date),
         Dv50 = as.numeric(Dv50)) 

date_breaks <- Dv50Data |>
  distinct(Date) |>
  pull(Date)

Dv50Data |>
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Dv50, color = Treatment)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  ylim(0,50) +
  labs(title = "Dose Response: Dv50 Particle Size Over Time",
       y = "Particle Size (microns)") + 
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks, date_labels = '%m/%d/%y') +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30, hjust = 1),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())


Evenly spacing dates on axis
Requested in comment
To make the date labels spaced evenly, treat them as character strings instead of dates.
Dv50Data |>
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(Date), y = Dv50, color = Treatment, group = Treatment)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  ylim(0,50) +
  labs(title = "Dose Response: Dv50 Particle Size Over Time",
       y = "Particle Size (microns)", x = "Date") + 
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30, hjust = 1),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())


Created on 2024-05-24 with reprex v2.1.0

Hey great thank you. I'll try that. Any way to space the dates out  evenly on the X axis?

@RayzedByRobots I've edited the answer to include plots with the Dates plotted as dates and another where they're plotted as categorical labels.

Thank you for doing it that way. Yes categories would behave differently that an actual date. Thanks for pointing that out to me. I'll try this this afternoon, then mark it as solved.
